# ОС Linux Debian 11 не работают звуковая карта , сетевой адаптер

Tags: linux, debian

Вопрос по IRBIS-NB264
Коллеги обращаюсь по следующему вопросу.
Куплен ноутбук, вот его характеристики:

Имя устройства: IRBIS-NB264
Процессор: Intel(R) Celeron(R) N4020 CPU @ 1.10GHz   1.10 GHz
Оперативная память: 4,00 ГБ (доступно: 3,82 ГБ)
Тип системы: 64-разрядная операционная система, процессор x64
ОС: Windows® 10 Pro
Твердотельный диск (SSD): EMMC, объем жесткого диска - 128 Гб
Сетевой адаптер: Realtek RTL8723B Wireless LAN 802.11n USB 2.0 Network Adapter

Звуковые, игровые и видеоустройства: ESAuDriver Device
Поставщик драйвера: Everest Semiconductor Co.

Дополнительно:
Расширена память: SSD M.2 2280 - 128 ГБ
ОС: Linux Debian 11

Цель покупки: обучение работе в Linux Debian

Возникшие проблемы:

1. При установке ОС Linux Debian 11 был нюанс со звуковой картой. Debian не смогла найти драйвер и признаюсь, я тоже. Но, ОС установилась.
2. Возник сбой с сетевым адаптером Realtek RTL8723B Wireless LAN 802.11n USB 2.0 Network Adapter. Debian не смогла найти драйвер и признаюсь, я тоже. Но, ОС установилась.
   В итоге:
3. При загрузке с ОС Windows® 10 все устройства работают хорошо. Стабильно.
4. При загрузке с ОС Linux Debian возникли следующие вопросы, нет звука, не работает WI-FI.
   Для решения возникшего вопроса в ОС Linux со звуком купил внешнюю USB звуковую карту UGREEN. Работает.
   Для решения вопроса с сетевым адаптером – купил модуль Wi-Fi Telefunken TF-UW01, совместим с Linux. Устройство в целом работает, но подключается через раз, а то, и после нескольких перезагрузок.

Коллеги. Подскажите пожалуйста новичку, как просто и без волшебства решить данные вопросы. Что делать?
Если бы в Linux было бы, что-то похожее на диспетчер устройств – я бы просто отключил указанные выше неработающие устройства, но такого не нашел.
А, если и возможно в Linux отключить сетевой адаптер и звуковую карту, чтобы купленные устройства работали стабильно, не повлияет ли это на их работу, когда я буду использовать ОС Windows? Мне тоже не понятно. И посоветоваться не с кем.
Благодарю за уделенное мне время.
Заранее благодарю.

Comment: *"просто и без волшебства решить данные вопросы"* - оставаться на Windows. Эксперименты с linux имеет смысл проводить на виртуальной машине.

Comment: Без волшебства - установить Ubuntu. Там есть драйверы сторонних производителей. Надо помнить про отличие философии Debian от Ubuntu. Если же разбираться с Debian, то одним постом и без физического доступа к ее терминалу, помочь словами практически невозможно - разве что искать в сети похожую проблему на форумах и повторять действия.

Comment: Читать, гуглить. Вполне возможно, что установка реалтековских фирмварей поможет с адаптером. Обратите внимание, что сам Реалтек не в курсе существования микросхемы RTL8723B. BU есть, BS есть, BE есть, B — нет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтоб запустить железо на дебиан нужно firmware. Для начала попробуй установить [из этих пакетов](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=firmware&searchon=names&suite=stable&section=all).

```
firmware-linux firmware-linux-free firmware-linux-nonfree firmware-misc-nonfree firmware-realtek
```

Или  [из этого сборника](https://github.com/q3aql/drivers-linux-firmware/releases)

Если не взлетит - нужно смотреть вывод `dmesg`. Там могут быть варианты по звуку и вайфаю:

- устройство хочет другой какой-то фирмвари или специального драйвера - гуглить конкретное устройство в этом случае
- устройство вообще не видно - нужно добавлять его специальным скриптом
- устройство есть, драйвер есть, но не включается - нужны пляски с acpi

Comment: Здравствуйте, eri. Спасибо за ответ. Посмотрел ваш Профиль. Вы Гуру. Мое Уважение. Буду стараться получить положительный результат.